# Laravel 5.1 method 'orderBy' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package

got a problem with Ordering in Laravel 5.1. I'm new to Laravel and my php skills aren't that good.

**When I use ordering with the Query Builder it works** like this

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
->where('post_status', 'draft')
->where('post_type', 'post')
->orderBy('post_date', 'asc')
->get();
```

**When I try to use Eloquent it doesn't** like this

```
$posts = Post::query()
->where('post_status', 'draft')
->where('post_type', 'post')
->orderBy('post_date', 'asc')
->get();
```

Anyone ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** I found the problem. I was using jgrossi/corcel and it already had ordering in its Builder. So I couldn't do it from the controller.

Comment: I can't see the difference between the two expressions !! + you have a type problem in `orderBy(#post_date', 'asc')` should be `orderBy('#post_date', 'asc')`.

Comment: that was a typo in here.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the wrong expression twice? As @ZakariaAcharki said, it's the exact same thing.

Comment: Oh. Now it's correct

Comment: did you try to add orderBy in the model ?

Comment: Got the solution. I'm using jgrossi/corcel and he integrated the ordering in the builder.

Comment: How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: You have to write the answer to your own quetion and mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just have to wait till tomorrow to mark it as correct :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corcel creator here :-)

Using Corcel with Laravel 5+ you have to include the namespace like `Corcel\Post` to refer to the `Post` class. If you want to setup your own connection name:

```
class Post extends Corcel\Post {
    protected $connection = 'connection-name';
}
```

And yes! The `Post` builder already order the posts :-)

Any question just ask! Best regards and thanks for using Corcel.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `query()` expression :

```
 $posts = Post::where('post_status', 'draft')
 ->where('post_type', 'post')
 ->orderBy('post_date', 'asc')
 ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't help. Without the 'query()' it doesn't find the 'where' method.

Comment: @nils Did you just remove the `query()` or did you also change the `->` to `::`? You need to treat the first where expression as a static method.

Comment: I tried it like this: Post::where('post_status', 'draft')
                     ->where('post_type', 'post')
                     ->orderBy('post_date', 'desc')
                     ->get();

Comment: Correct syntax, what you get in $posts ?

Comment: Could it be the format? post_date looks like this [2015-08-05 09:41:40]

Comment: I can read the post_date and display it, just the ordering fails.

Comment: there was a warning in phpstorm which showed method not found. but there wasn't an error. but found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the namespaces for your model? The previous answer should work fine

Comment: Yep. I did add the namespace.

Comment: Try with '='    where('post_type','=','post')

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was using jgrossi/corcel and it already had ordering in its Builder. So I couldn't do it from the controller.

Answer (score -2):

do you add

```
use App\Post;
```

Maybe is good idea to paste exception
..
One thing i know with Laravel ... if it works in tinker and doesnt work in view the mistake is in controller or view ... so check tinker